# Selecting duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id| country  |
===================
1 | Argelia  | 
2 | USA      |
3 | China    |
4 | Italy    |
4 | Italy    |
6 | USA      |
7 | USA      |
1 | Argelia  |
```

I want a query that selects duplicate countries, but only when the ids are different. Thus, from the table above, the query would produce something like:

```
id| country  |
===================
2 | USA      |
6 | USA      |
7 | USA      |
```

Italy and Argelia are duplicate countries as well but since they shared an id, they shouldn't be in the output. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.country 
FROM   countries c 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT country, 
                          COUNT(DISTINCT id) k 
                   FROM   countries 
                   GROUP  BY country 
                   HAVING k > 1) t 
         ON c.country = t.country
```

[see it working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ade58/15)

Comment: They want the output where the IDs do not match, I think this will have to be a sub-select.

Comment: Thanks but not working... it just takes the count into account, without caring if the values are equal or different, so it is also returning Argelia and Italy.

Comment: @Matthew doh what was I thinking fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT country, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS cnt, GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY country, id
HAVING cnt > 1
```

Comment: Thanks but not working... it just takes the count into account, without caring if the values are equal or different, so it is also returning Argelia and Italy.

Comment: oops. try `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` then